# TypeScript: Constructor Property is declared but never used

Tags: javascript, typescript

currently studying and new to TypeScript.

I am trying to create a class and using a constructor to initiate private variables inside this class, however, I get hit with a `[property name] is declared but never used`.

```js
export class CloClient extends Client {
    private identity: string[];
    private commands: { [name: string]: typeof CommandClass };
    private behaviors: { [name: string]: typeof Behavior };

    constructor(identity: string[], options: ClientOptions) {
        super(options);
        
        this.identity = identity;

        this.commands = {};
        this.behaviors = {};
    }
}
```

Using TypeScript 4.4.3, any suggestions?

Comment: This is not an error this is just a Typescript warning! it just tells you that you have an unused code inside it. if it's not important then just remove it.

Comment: Please provide a [mre] that clearly demonstrates the issue you are facing.  Ideally someone could drop the code into a standalone IDE like [The TypeScript Playground (link here!)](https://tsplay.dev/wgL5MN) and immediately get to work solving the problem without first needing to re-create it.  So there should be no typos, unrelated errors, or undeclared types or values.

Comment: You're using eslint right? you could disable this rule to your `.tsconfig.json`, `.eslintrc.json` or `eslintConfig` in package.json. e.g `"@typescript-eslint/no-unused-vars" : "off"` or read this: https://eslint.org/docs/rules/no-unused-vars, although you shouldn't turn this hint off

Answer (score 0):

That warning will be displayed for all properties which are declared but are never accessed.

Typescript is trying to inform you that in its current state, that property does not need to exist as it is never used during the execution of the script.

Once you access / read from the property than this warning will disappear. i.e some thing like:

```
if(this.identity){
... other code
}
```